# Make an emarginated plot in matplotlib/pyplot, like on a design drawing

Tags: matplotlib

I need to make a plot with the cut edges, something like this:
[image]

The right and bottom edges should be a polygon, like on a design drawing. No ticks or labels are needed there. No clippings is assumed (actually plot will be strictly inside of the polygon area). Is there easy way for this?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? I would simply draw these polygons.

Comment: Guess I will if nobody will give the receipt. Remember I've seen this possibility in a some commercial plotting routine, so I thought it may be claimed in the Matplotlib also.

Comment: Well, asking others to do your work is always a bit problematic :)  AFAIK there is no such "break" option in matplotlib yet, hence you will draw this yourself. Breaking axes is common to some plotting routines (e.g. PyX), however, this feature is typically different to what you want here!

Comment: Man, asking somebody for somewhat is always tricky. If you're having nothing to say in re, please go.